# EF Core SQL Exception in saving a model with a foreign key of an Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have 2 models. `Client` and `AgentUser`. `Client` is just a normal EF model and `AgentUser` is an Identity model. `Client` has a foreign key of `AgentUser`. When I create a new instance of `Client` and set the property to an instance of `AgentUser` and save it to database, it produces and SQL Exception.

AgentUser.cs

```
public class AgentUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string AgentType { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public string? ReferrerId { get; set; }
    public virtual AgentUser Referrer { get; set; }
    public virtual List<AgentUser> Referrals { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Client> Clients { get; set; }

}
```

Client.cs

```
public class Client
    {
        public int ClientId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Company { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string? Email { get; set; }

        [Phone]
        public string? PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string? Address { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string? City { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string? State { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(6)]
        public string? ZipCode { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
        public string? ReferrerId { get; set; }
        public virtual AgentUser Referrer { get; set; }
    }
```

Razor Page handler for saving `Client` instance to database:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string? returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/Member/Clients/Index");
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Client newClient = new Client()
                {
                    Company = Input.Company,
                    FirstName = Input.FirstName,
                    LastName = Input.LastName,
                    Email = Input.Email,
                    PhoneNumber = Input.PhoneNumber,
                    Address = Input.Address,
                    City = Input.City,
                    State = Input.State,
                    ZipCode = Input.ZipCode,
                    DateAdded = DateTime.UtcNow.Date
                };

                if (Input.ReferrerId != null)
                {
                    AgentUser referrer = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(Input.ReferrerId);
                    if (referrer == null)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, $"There is no agent with the id: {Input.ReferrerId}");
                        return Page();
                    }

                    newClient.Referrer = referrer;
                }

                await _context.Clients.AddAsync(newClient);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToPage(returnUrl);
            }
            return Page();
        }
```

SQL Exception:

> SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY
> SAME TABLE constraint "FK_AgentUser_AgentUser_ReferrerId". The
> conflict occurred in database "mydb", table "dbo.AgentUser",
> column 'Id'. The statement has been terminated.

Comment: You can have only one row of database with a primary key.  With SQL Server you have to check if key exists.  If it exists you use update instead of insert.  You can also when you get an exception just update instead of checking before you do the insert.

Comment: That page handler is for adding new `Client`. `AgentUser` can add new `Client` and the page handler creates a new instance of the `Client` and set the `Referrer` field to the `AgentUser` who adds the client.

Comment: If the client already exists in database you are adding a duplicate and getting an exception.  So either you have to check before creating new client or when exception occurs handle the exception.

Comment: But the Client table is empty. The error only occurs when I set the `Referrer` property of the new instance of `Client`

Comment: Of Course, Of Course.  The entity class should be an image of the database.  If the actual database contains the Client than you will get an error when you insert unless you empty the database when you run the c# application.